# Laravel Localization 2 lang website return wrong locales

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel5.5 ,I want to make 2 lang website ,  when I try to use  `return App::getLocale();` 
and I go `/en/test` It should return `en` and `/sv/test` It should return `sv` but now It only return `en`

first I set up in my config.app

```
'locales' => ['en' => 'English', 'sv => 'Sweden'],
```

After that I setup my middleware language.php

```
 if (Session::has('applocale') AND array_key_exists(Session::get('applocale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
    App::setLocale(Session::get('applocale'));
}
else { // This is optional as Laravel will automatically set the fallback language if there is none specified
    App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
}
return $next($request);
```

Then In my  kernel.php I setup routemiddleware

```
'language' => \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
```

last thing I set up my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','language']  ,'prefix' => 'sv' ], function () {
    Route::get('/test', function(){
        return App::getLocale();
    });
});


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','language']  ,'prefix' => 'en' ], function () {
    Route::get('/test', function(){
        return \App::getLocale();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You so not config language names, just codes (aside from that it's `Svenska`)

```
'locales' => ['en', 'sv'];
```